# ps: Clean way to only get parent processes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, ps

I use `ps ef` and `ps rf` a lot.

Here is a sample output for `ps rf`:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3476 pts/0    S      0:00 su ...
 3477 pts/0    S      0:02  \_ bash
 8062 pts/0    T      1:16      \_ emacs -nw ...
15733 pts/0    R+     0:00      \_ ps xf
15237 ?        S      0:00 uwsgi ...
15293 ?        S      0:00  \_ uwsgi ...
15294 ?        S      0:00  \_ uwsgi ...
```

And today I needed to retrieve only the **master process** of uwsgi in a script (so I want only 15237 but not 15293 nor 15294).

As of today, I tried some `ps rf | grep -v ' \\_ '`... but I would like a **cleaner way**.

I also came accross another solution from unix.com's forums:

```
ps xf | sed '1d' | while read pid tty stat time command ; do [ -n "$(echo $command | egrep '^uwsgi')" ] && echo $pid ; done
```

But still a **lot of pipes** and **ugly tricks**.

Is there really no `ps` option or cleaner tricks (maybe using **awk**) to accomplish that?

Comment: Why pass the `f` output modifier if you don't want it?

Comment: If you checked there is no suitable option of `ps` (I assume you did) then can you really imagine an 'awk' snippet simpler than what you did with `grep`?

Comment: @netcoder I guess you need the `f` in order to know which process is the parent and which are the children.

Comment: Personally I ended up with `ps -aef --forest | grep chrome | grep -v grep | awk 'NR==1' | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After discussing with @netcoder on his answer's comments he used a nice trick :D
Using `f` on `ps` will always get the parent on top which is great.

This should just work:

```
$ ps hf -opid -C <process> | awk '{ print $1; exit }'
```

as I mention on the comments, this will return the `pid` of just one process.

---

I would go with:

```
ps rf -opid,cmd -C <process-name> | awk '$2 !~ /^[|\\]/ { print $1 }'
```

that is:

- list running processses `r` (or `e` if you want everything)
- along with parent/children graph `f`
- output only the pid and command name `-opid,cmd`
- only for the given process `-C <process>`

and then

- if the 2nd field - which is the command (`-opid,cmd`) - does not start with a `\` or `|` then it is a parent process, so print the 1st field - which is the pid.

---

simple test:

```
$ ps f -opid,cmd -Cchromium
  PID CMD
 2800 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=zygote --enable-seccomp-sandbox
 2803  \_ /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=zygote --enable-seccomp-sandbox
 2899      \_ /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=renderer --enable-seccomp-sandbox --lang=en-US --force-fieldtrials=ConnCountImpact/conn_count_6/ConnnectB
 2906      |   \_ /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=renderer --enable-seccomp-sandbox --lang=en-US --force-fieldtrials=ConnCountImpact/conn_count_6/Connn
 [  ... snip ... ]
 2861      \_ /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=renderer --enable-seccomp-sandbox --lang=en-US --force-fieldtrials=ConnCountImpact/conn_count_6/ConnnectB
 2863          \_ /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=renderer --enable-seccomp-sandbox --lang=en-US --force-fieldtrials=ConnCountImpact/conn_count_6/Connn
 2794 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --enable-seccomp-sandbox --memory-model=low --purge-memory-button --disk-cache-dir=/tmp/chromium
 2796  \_ /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --enable-seccomp-sandbox --memory-model=low --purge-memory-button --disk-cache-dir=/tmp/chromium
 3918  \_ /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=gpu-process --channel=2794.45.1891443837 --gpu-vendor-id=0x10de --gpu-device-id=0x0611 --gpu-driver-version -
25308  \_ [chromium] <defunct>
31932  \_ /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so --lang=en-US --channel=2794.1330.1990362572


$ ps f -opid,cmd -Cchromium | awk '$2 !~ /^[|\\]/ { print $1 }'
PID
2800
2794

$ # also supressing the header of ps (top line 'PID') -- add 'h' to ps
$ ps hf -opid,cmd -Cchromium | awk '$2 !~ /^[|\\]/ { print $1 }'
2800
2794
```

Comment: Well you kind integrated my answer into yours eh? ;-) I'll delete mine. Have a +1.

Comment: Nice ideas here, and the `awk` line is A solution to what I was looking for

Comment: Instead of the whole awk thing you can simply `grep -v '\\_'`.

Comment: Nice solution, you have my +1! One can also omit the `-C <command>` option to list all parent processes.

Answer (score 8):

```
/usr/bin/pgrep -o <process_name>
```

*where '-o' is the oldest (least recently started) of the matching processes*

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (from [here](http://pub.mouraf.org/blog/2010/09/bash-how-to-find-the-parent-process-name/)):

```
ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you simply save the pid of the master in a file (pidfile) with the --pidfile option ? If it is not a viable solution you can give a custom name to the master process with --procname-master .

Using ps for that kind of things is highly unreliable (race conditions all over the place, and special cases invalidating parsing rules...)

Comment: Yes I know about `--pidfile` and `--pidfile2`, but 1. it does not detect other running instances 2. it takes some time to be written. I known ps-tricks is not the best option, but I was curious about how to to this in a better way while using ps, mostly for learning purposes

Answer (score 0):

It is an other solution to get master process ID of a process.Tall, but nice.

```
pstree -p 1 |grep <proc_name>|sed -n 1p|tr -d "|,-"|sed 's/(/ /g'|sed 's/)/ /g'|tr -d "+"|awk {'print $2'};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely assume that you only have one parent process with n children, or that you only care about the 'earliest' of several parent processes (lowest PID), then I think this simpler solution works just fine.

```
ps h -opid -C<commandname> | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

By filename (outputs the number of parents):

```sh
o=""; for p in $(pgrep -f example.sh); do o="${o}$(pstree -lp | grep -nF \($p\))\n"; done; echo -e "$o" | cut -f2 -d: | cut -f2 -d- | sort -n | grep -vE ^$ | uniq -c | awk '$1>0' | wc -l
```

**Edit:** I previously used

```sh
| cut -f1 -d: |
```

But apparently there is no guarantee that child processes will follow one after another so I ended up with counting parent processes by their name and pid:

```sh
| cut -f2 -d: | cut -f2 -d- |
```

Answer (score -1):

From key words KEYWORD

```
ps aux | grep -i KEYWORD | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'|sort -h|head -1|xargs kill
```

BTW, is this assumption that parent process ID is the smallest ID valid？？？？

Comment: Three years later: no, it's not valid.  A child can have a lower PID than its parent if the PIDs wrap around (which, by default, happens at 32768)