# Print parent shell process within python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I want to log the parent command which ultimately executed my Python script. I want to captured it within the Python subprocess so I may include it in existing logs.

I have a shell script `run.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

python runme.py "$@"
```

And `runme.py` contains:

```
import sys
import subprocess

print("Doing stuff...")

# What command called me?
psoutput = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '--no-headers','-o','cmd'], text=True)
cmds = psoutput.strip().split('\n')
print(cmds[0])
```

I execute this from my company's shell (on [RHEL](https://www.redhat.com/en/engage/economic-impact-rhel-s-201904230659?sc_cid=7013a000002w1FtAAI&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3sX864j4-QIVDP3jBx0D1QJrEAAYASAAEgJqKvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)) like this, and it outputs...

```
$ ./run.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
Doing stuff...
run.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Looks good! But if another process is running first, it shows up first in `ps` and this doesn't work:

```
$ sleep 10s &
$ ./run.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
Doing stuff...
sleep 10s
```

I'm really trying to select my parent process from `ps`. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373512/5289570) uses `-C <process-name>` but I don't know what my process name is. Following this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/153979/982449) I've tried this with several similar ideas for process name:

```
subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-o', 'ppid=', '-C', 'python runme.py'], text=True)
```

But that outputs a lot of numbers that look like PID's, but none seem related to my bash call.

How can I reliably get my parent process from within Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure python solution.
It works under any shell.
The parent cmd line result is a list with the command and the arguments.

```
import psutil
import os

ppid = psutil.Process(os.getppid())
print(ppid.cmdline())
```

Comment: This combined with process [parents](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.parents) was what I needed in a more general case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One (okay) solution I realized while writing my question:

`run.sh` contains

```
command_run=$(echo "$BASH_SOURCE $@")
runme.py --command-run "$command_run" "$@"
```

`runme.py` contains

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-c', '--command-run', required=False,
    default=None, dest='command_run',
    help='Command text passed from bash'
)
args = parser.parse_args()

print("Doing stuff...")
print(args.command_run)
```

Additional arguments can be passed after adding more parsing. As above, the following works now:

```
$ sleep 5s &
$ ./run.sh
Doing stuff...
run.sh
```

I'll mark this answer as correct unless someone has a nicer solution than passing $BASH_SOURCE this way.